# Transition/Transform CSS property isn't sliding in as expected

Tags: css

So, my objective here is to have the div slide in once the state (React) value is met, but all it ever does is abruptly appear instead of slide in from off the screen.

```css
.network-message {
 position: relative;
 top: -67px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 5vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: red;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: calc(15px + (17 - 15) * (100vw - 1440px) / (2560 - 1440));
 align-items: center;
 transition: transform 1s ease-in;
 transform: translateY(67px);

 .network-button {
  margin-left: 2em;

  button {
   border: none;
   padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
   background-color: #254294;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: calc(11px + (13 - 11) * (100vw - 1440px) / (2560 - 1440));
   cursor: pointer;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class='network-message'>
  Looks like Microsoft's CRM is down at the moment. Please be patient
  while they work to resolve the issue.
  <div class='network-button'>
    <button type='button'>
      OK
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once this 'state' is met you should add another class to .network-message which applies the new styling with `top:0` for example. Then the transition to this position will start. And I'd set the top initially to -5vh, since that is the height of the element, if you want it to be hidden completely.

Comment: Thanks @Esger, that made sense and worked.  I needed to have an element visible to the DOM before the transition took place.